# div with 100% width including margins

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, spacing

I am trying to create a layout in which stacked divs take up the full width of the page including a 3px buffer on either side. In other words, I don't want them to run right into the edges of the screen, but I still want them sized based on the screen width.

I have managed to get this 3px margin between the divs using padding, but I am having trouble with the horizontal spacing. How do I add padding that is included in the 100% width?

Here's what I have so far:

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="contentContainer first">
        <div class="content"> content 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentContainer">
        <div class="content"> content 2 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentContainer">
        <div class="content"> content 3 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.container .contentContainer{
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container .contentContainer .content {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
}

.container .first {
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

You can see my attempt in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4z9jcsp/). You will notice that my `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` are having the desired effect, but the `padding-left` and `padding-right` aren't.

thanks!

Comment: If you want a `margin`, why use `padding` instead of `margin`?

Comment: Try using margin instead of padding. Padding is the space between the content and the border, as opposed to margin, which is the space outside the border. This should help you get what you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

be sure to use `box-sizing: border-box` when using `padding` to force the padding to behave like it should. As far as the horizontal padding goes, you can just add `padding: 0 3px;` to `.container`

```
*{ //adds to all elements or you can just add to the ones that use padding
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;    
}

.container{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0 3px; <-----add this
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z4z9jcsp/1/)

Comment: Thanks @jmore!
could you explain to me in more detail what `box-sixing` does?

Comment: @kat yeah so adding padding doesn't count towards an elements `width`, so a `div` that has a `width` of `100px` with 5px of `padding` on either side will actually be 110px wide. `box-sizing: border-box` forces the `padding` inward so the final size is 100px even with the `padding` added. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

By default, border and padding are not included in the width calculation. So `border: 1px; padding: 3px; width: 100%;` adds 8 pixels to the width (4 pixels on either side), which causes the element to overflow outside its parent.

Use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). This will make the browser *include* border and padding when it calculates the width.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4z9jcsp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

This way you don't need the unnecessary divs. Give padding on the container.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content"> content 1 </div>
<div class="content"> content 2 </div>
<div class="content"> content 3 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
border: 1px solid gray;
padding:3px 3px 0 3px;
margin-bottom:3px;
}

.container .content {
border: 1px solid gray;
height: 75px;
margin-bottom:3px;
}
```